# WSO2 ESB Topic Subscription for REST url

Tags: rest, soap, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

We are successfully using WSO2 ESB for basic mediation using REST for the caller and the service (via a message queue).

We are now trying to use the topics and subscription model. However, unlike in other parts of the ESB where you can modify the message format to POX, in the subscription interface there is way to define the format of the payload to the URL. The ESB always sends soap to the URL, even though we want it to send POX. We don;t want to have to write SOAP services.

Is there way to change the format that the subscriber gets? I know we can setup a proxy which then sends the message etc, but this is cumbersome and cannot be automated for new services.

Answer (score 0):

If you use WS-Eventing, then you get the soap messages to the subscriber endpoints. You can use JMS based pub-sub scenario to implement what you want. Please have a look at [1].

[1] http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/12/wso2-esb-example-pubsub-soa